# How can get x and y position of an image in android on onCreate?

Tags: android, coordinates, android-imageview, oncreate, co

I want current **X & Y** co ordinates of an ImageView on **onCreate**  of **Activity**, is there any solution for the same ? Please share your idea on same.

Comment: in onCreate there is no display measured yet. you cannot (unless you explicitely measure your layout)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you call `setContentView()` the Android nutshell starts the views drawing on surface, Which you can observe on using `viewTrewwObserve` So you can not get the height and width of `ImageView` in `onCreate()` as its not currently draw yet.

You can use, (Not tried)

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
 new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // Get ImageView height width here <------------
  }
});
```

It will Register a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.

**Update:**

Or you can use  [`onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29).

This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user. The default implementation clears the key tracking state, so should always be called.

Answer (score 0):

(1)You can get it using the `getViewTreeObserver()` or (2)you can add an asynchronous Task on your `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //SIMPLY CALL YOUR ASYN TASK WITH DELAY OVER HERE LIKE THIS.

  new MyImageDrawClass().execute();
}



class MyImageDrawClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        value_wdth = mContent.getWidth();
        value_hght = mContent.getHeight();

        //PERFORM YOUR OTHER DRAWING STUFF..
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

let me know if you find issue with this, you can also reduce the time delay to `Thread.sleep(10);`
I generally use this method to get height and to get width.

Comment: This is a complete hack.  Thread.sleep() is used far too often, usually for bad things.  This is a bad thing.  Artificially creating a delay in the "hope" that the layout completes in time.  Yeuch.

Comment: your right about it, but i have already mentioned the `"1)You can get it using the getViewTreeObserver()"` and this was just another solution if he wishes to achieve it that way, the hack seems to work just fine for me.