# Perform click on button in Android SDK

Tags: android, button, automation, click

As soon as the layout is created I want a button to be clicked automatically and I use `button.performClick()` for that.

The problem is that it doesn't work. It looks like I can't do that during the `onCreate, onStart, onResume` method. At what point is the button and its events created, so I can perform a click on it?

This

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mybutton.performClick();
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706886/how-can-get-x-and-y-position-of-an-image-in-android/14707052#14707052

Comment: are you sure that doing `setContentView()`, `findViewById()`, `setOnClickListener()` and `performClick()` does not work? I'm just curious!

Comment: They work. The button is just not clicked, but I don't get any error

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This worked for me in a similar case:

```
mybutton.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 mybutton.performClick();
            }
});
```

This way the runnable will run only if the button is already loaded on the layout.

Comment: I like the post runnable but it turns out that the OP was doing it wrong -.-

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html):

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mybutton.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            mybutton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That would be a good choice in my situation if I would test this on devices with API>16

Answer (score 3):

What I smell, seem you forget to add [onClicklistner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to your view, I tested your way its works fine,
I did something like below:

define Button globally `Button btn;`

within `onCreate()`

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog();
                }
            });
```

and within `onResume()`

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        btn.performClick();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

*It successfully showing a dialog!*

Comment: Yes, I had setOnTouchListener instead of setOnClickListener. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    myButton.performClick();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: funny that he asks a question having the answer in the question :)